# Form fields after click the save button read only(view)

Tags: forms, readonly

i want to make some of form fields (ready only) after when user fill his/her profile information in form input fields and click the save button after that these fields show as (read only).

below is the form fields that  i want to make like it.

```
<tr>
        <td class="widget-title"><font color="blue">Bank Details</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <table cellpadding="4" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="50%">
                    Bank Name:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bank" id="bank" value="{$user.bnk}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="right" width="50%">
                    Bank Account Number:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="baccount" id="baccount" value="{$user.bnkact}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="right" width="50%">
                    Bank Account Title:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="btitle" id="btitle" value="{$user.bnktit}"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" width="50%">
                    Bank Branch Code:
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bcode" id="bcode" value="{$user.bnkcd}"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the `<input type="submit">`/ submit button to submit the data?

Add this button to your code

```
<input type="submit" id="save" onClick="hide()" value="save">
```

Then add a javascript function within the `<script></script>` tags or in a .js page which is included before the button

This will be your function according to the given code:

```
function hide(){
  document.getElementById("bank").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("baccount").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("btitle").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("bcode").disabled = true;
}
```

So the full code will be in html:

```
<input type="submit" id="save" onClick="hide()" value="save">
```

OR

```
<input type="button" id="save" onClick="hide()" value="save">
```

And in javascript
    `function hide(){
      document.getElementById("bank").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("baccount").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("btitle").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("bcode").disabled = true;
    }`

Comment: thanks for your reply but i need some more help that i want to use this code in smarty template page is it work ?